# What does -= and += mean in the function?

Tags: vim, completion

```
au FileType php call PHPFuncList()    
function PHPFuncList()    
    set dictionary-=/etc/vim/php_funclist.txt dictionary+=/etc/vim/php_funclist.txt    
    set complete-=k complete+=k    
endfunction
```

For the PHPFunctionList above, two lines in function body confused me.

```
set dictionary-=/etc/vim/php_funclist.txt dictionary+=/etc/vim/php_funclist.txt    
set complete-=k complete+=k
```

For the two lines ,first `-=` to remove it and then `+=` to add it again.

Why can't write the two lines just `+=` in them?

```
set dictionary+=/etc/vim/php_funclist.txt    
set complete+=k
```

Are there any differences between them?
`:h set-=` point out that  When the option is a list of flags, `{value}` must be  exactly as they appear in the option.  Remove flags one by one to avoid problems.
To avoid which problem?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would guess the developer did not understand how `+=` works, and was using `-=` to ensure things were not added twice.

Answer (score 6):

In vim doc :

```
:h :set+=
```

and

```
:h :set-=
```

has explained the usage clearly. basically the `+=` will append an element to the option, and `-=` will substract the value from the option.

Comment: To add it with += directly has the same effect,in my opinion.